# How do I display the Stereo Interlace effect in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view, stereoscopy

when enabling stereocopy，  it displays red and blue images， but I want it to display interlace real time.   how do I  get it to display the effect I want? I need to have the thing playing real time，then I can wear my 3D glasses to watch it.

Comment: Have you tested that your graphics card and monitor can properly display interlaced 3D? According to the docs setting the *Stereo Mode* to *Interlace* should work https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/multiview/usage.html

Comment: Not yet，but I think it won't work，since the red and blue color is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out，I need to click the top left "window" menu "set stereo system 3D" instead of the stereoscopy in the "output", it's working now